# Existem ambientes online de aprendizagem de programação com exercícios práticos e desafios para C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Existem alguns sites, tal como o [URI Online Judge](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br), que permitem aos programadores praticarem programação e compartilhar conhecimento através de exerícios específicos e desafios lógicos e matemáticos.

Porém alguns são restritos quanto à linguagem. O mencionado acima, por exemplo, aceita apenas respostas em C++ e Java.

É possível encontrar outros ambientes de aprendizagem de programação que aceitem outras linguagens, preferencialmente com suporte à **C#**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alguns sites que aceitam `C#`:

- [TopCoder](http://www.topcoder.com/tc)
- [CodeJam](http://code.google.com/codejam/)
- [USACO Training Program](http://train.usaco.org/usacogate)
- [CodeChef](http://www.codechef.com/)
- [Sphere Online Judge](http://www.spoj.pl/)
- [Timus Online Judge](http://acm.timus.ru/)
- [ProjectEuler](http://projecteuler.net/)
- [CodeEval](https://www.codeeval.com)
- [Code Hunt](https://www.codehunt.com/)